# Open seadragon for android

Tags: android, deepzoom

I want to achieve the deep zoom effect in android. But it seems really hard. So, can I use HTML5, and use the javascript library `Open Seadragon`? Or, how can I achieve this goal using native android API?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could use OpenSeadragon in a web view. You might also check out the deep zoom feature in Ion:

https://plus.google.com/110558071969009568835/posts/JqrbkHAmDju

I'm not familiar with Android development, so there may be other options...